# Merging texts in for loop from Gallica XML newspapers issues

Tags: r

I want to gather ocerized texts from the french newspaper Ouest Eclair (year 1915).
The ocerized text is available from Gallica, the french digital library.

```
 library(httr)
 library(xml2)
 library(tidyverse)


 # Newspapers issues identifiers calls arks. They are scrapped from Gallica (XML) and parsed to data frame object


  r <- GET("https://gallica.bnf.fr/services/Issues?ark=ark:/12148/cb41193663x/date&date=1916")

 ouest_eclair <- r %>%
  content() %>% 
 xml_find_all(".//issue") %>% 
 map_df(~ c(as.list(xml_attrs(.x)), date_parution = xml_text(.x)))

 # keep only the good colum withs identifiers
 arks2 <- ouest_eclair[,'ark']




#  The library htm2txt is used to extract easily text from an html page. 

 library(htm2txt)

# Here's the loop

    for (i in arks2) {
        url <- paste0("https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/", i, ".texteBrut")
        print(url)
        txt <- gettxt(url) 
          txt <- paste(txt,txt)
         Sys.sleep(1)
                }
```

My questions : how to merge all the texts in **one** txt object inside the loop avoiding to have 2 times the first text?

Comment: Store them within a variable and use `paste`

Comment: Alternative to a `for` loop may be `lapply(c("bpt6k5674481", "bpt6k567454v", "bpt6k567462f"), function(i) gettext(paste0("https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/", i, ".texteBrut")))` which returns a `list` of returned texts.

Comment: @ sboysel I want to keep my for loop and merge all the texts in **one** objet. Not a list.

Comment: `paste(list("a", "b"), collapse = "\n")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `arks2` is a data frame, you can try the following with the trick `unlist(arks2)`:

```
txt <- c()
for (i in unlist(arks2)) {
  url <- paste0("https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/", arks2[k,], ".texteBrut")
  print(url)
  txt <- c(txt,gettxt(url))
  # Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

**Alternative** method:

```
txt <- sapply(unlist(arks2), function(v) gettxt(paste0("https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/", v, ".texteBrut")))
```

Comment: it works great but my real data is a dataframe column...so it doesn't work :Error in file(con, "r")

Comment: @Wilcar do you mean `arks2` is a data frame or something else? Could you provide some example for the data frame as input? I guess it is not difficult, but I need to know how the data frame looks like

Comment: Error in file(con, "r") : invalid 'description' argument

Comment: @Wilcar see my updated solution, where You can use `unlist(arks2)` in `for (i in arks2)`

Comment: Thank you for helping. What was the issue with the df?

Comment: @Wilcar I am not familiar with `tibble`, so I have no idea how to deal with it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are overwriting `txt` in every iteration of the loop. The trick is to start with one (empty) variable for the output that is defined *outside* of the loop and gets updated (not overwritten) in every iteration, in combination with another temporary variable that *does* get overwritten:

```
library(htm2txt)
arks2 <-  c("bpt6k5674481", "bpt6k567454v", "bpt6k567462f")

txt.output <- "" # start with an empty string of text before you start the loop
for (i in arks2) {
  url <- paste0("https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/", i, ".texteBrut")
  print(url)
  txt.temp <- gettxt(url) 
  txt.output <- paste(txt, txt.temp)
  Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

You don't actually need the temporary one though:

```
txt.output <- ""
for (i in arks2) {
  url <- paste0("https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/", i, ".texteBrut")
  print(url)
  txt.output <- paste(txt, gettxt(url))
  Sys.sleep(1)
}
```